# How to calculate mean and standard deviation of all features in a class identified by k-nearest neighbors?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

I have classified my data into several neighborhoods using k nearest neighbors. I need to efficiently calculate the mean and standard deviation for all features of data points belonging to a particular neighborhood. 
I am using sklearn.kneighbors.

Comment: Do you want the spatial mean and standard deviation? Like the average in each dimension of the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you append the predicted neighbourhood onto your data `df` (let's call this `neighbourhood`), then using `groupby` and `transform` within a loop should do the trick.

As an example:

```
features = [var_1,var_2,...] # a list of the features to run over
for col in features:
  df[col+'_mean'] = df.groupby('neighbourhood')[col].transform('mean')
```